# Malodorous transformer and the cleaning thereof

Tags: cleaning

I’ve bought a lab power supply of the variable transformer type, that unfortunately smells of cigarette smoke. I’ve tried airing it.

I need a gentle method for cleaning the outer windings that won’t hurt the enamel. My initial thought was bicarbonate of soda on a slightly damp toothbrush. Bicarbonate of soda is a mild abrasive and has odour absorbing properties.

[image: Inside the power supply]

Comment: You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: Is it really the transformer? I see a selenium rectifier on the right, and though I've never smelled one myself, I was told that they do give off an unpleasant odor when old and heated.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I’ve not plugged it in yet. The unit smells very much like cigarette smoke so my aim to clean the whole thing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller:  Dead selenium rectifiers stink like the dickens.  As long as they work, they shouldn't stink.

Comment: Thanks, @JRE! William, so, the thing is: I'd presume the smelling components are mostly organic, so a solvent for these would be advantageous – like acetone. But that's also the most likely to be aggressive towards the enamel. Hm. Maybe a mild ethanol, soap and water mixture and drying would help – warm windowcleaner?

Comment: I'd disassemble the whole thing, soak and scrub the case with household degreaser and a toothbrush, then tackle each component separately. Even then you won't get *all* of the smell... place it in a garbage bag with an open box of soda bicarbonate. Close and leave sit for a few weeks.

Comment: @JRE thinking about this: would it maybe be a good time to replace the selenium rectifier with a silicon one? One less thing to clean, and probably not hard to beat the performance of the original.

Comment: `"During catastrophic failure [selenium rectifiers] produced significant quantities of malodorous and highly toxic fumes that let the repair technician know what the problem was."` - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_rectifier). Get it checked out by someone who knows about them

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a good idea.  I cleaned up and went over an old tube radio a couple of weeks ago, and replaced the selenium rectifier and the electrolytic filter capacitors.  The rectifier was OK, but I figured as long as I had it disassembled I might as well go whole hog on it.  The old radio sounds much better now - no hum.

Comment: I was interested to learn about the selenium rectifier. I could see it was wired as a rectifier but couldn’t understand why it looked like that.

Comment: Bad selenium rectifiers don't smell at all like cigarette smoke, more like rotten eggs. A very characteristic odor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about removing the odor of cigarette smoke and is not related to electronics design.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The question is specifically about cleaning a transformer without injury to the enamel on the windings. The presence and nature of the smell is merely the motivation behind the question.

Comment: blow out the dust with compressed air